# Redux initialState is missing one key value pair

Tags: reactjs, redux

so I have a react typescript app with redux (toolkit+thunk) here is the reducer:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { findProduct } from "../helpers";
import { CartItem, Product } from "../types";

interface InitialState {
  cart: CartItem[];
  products: Product[];
}

const initialState: InitialState = {
  cart: [],
  products: [
    {
      name: "Pencil",
      availability: 24,
      price: 114,
      _uuid: "b7b0e060-e090-11ed-b5ea-0242ac120002",
    },
    {
      name: "Pen",
      availability: 12,
      price: 154,
      _uuid: "a300d6d8-e091-11ed-b5ea-0242ac120002",
    },
    {
      name: "Eraser",
      availability: 8,
      price: 135,
      _uuid: "a9a60f4e-e091-11ed-b5ea-0242ac120002",
    },
  ],
};

export const cart = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {}
});

export default cart.reducer;
```

```js
import './App.scss';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { IRootState, Product } from './types';

function App() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const products = useSelector((state: IRootState) => state.cart.products);
console.log(products)

  return (
    <div className="App h-screen w-screen">
        <div className=''>
        {products.map(product => (
          <div key={product._uuid} className='flex justify-between bg-emerald-200 my-2 p-2'>
            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>addToCart</button>
          </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I now want to access products and map over it, as you can see in the second snippet, but for some reasons the products key value pair is missing on the state when I log it, cart is showing up though.

Comment: You can print the whole state and see the data structure

Comment: @linDu I did, products doesnt show up.

Comment: Can you edit your question includes the debugging details and the code about creating the redux store

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue.

I needed to clear my localStorage to remove the persisted state object because it differs to the new initial state.